# Docusaurus V2 remove version label from doc pages

Tags: docusaurus

In each page of docs the label `Version: Next` is visible:

[image: screen of that label]

**Is there a way to disable and remove the label?**

Since I don't want to add multiple versions to my documents, I don't need the label.

Comment: I think this has been fixed in `alpha-64`, I had the same issue before.

Comment: @MarcusCemes I am using alpha-64 and have this label, I still can't find a way to remove it

Comment: UPDATE: I deleted folder node_modules and installed again, the version label went away

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.0.0-alpha.64 after deleting node_modules and installing again the problem solved